# Change cursor on any page text hover

Tags: css

If I change the default cursor of a site like so:

```
body { cursor: move; }
```

Then hovering text will no longer yield the text hover vertical line.

```css
body { 
  height: 20em;
  background: teal;
  cursor: move; 
}
```

```html
This is some text.  When you hover it, your cursor will not change
```

Is it possible to re-assert that the cursor should change on text hover?

If not, is it possible to only use the custom cursor when not hovering text?

---

Edit: my code is not inside any specific tag.  This is not an unrealistic example, this is what happens when you set a site wide custom cursor.

Comment: You can only target elements with CSS, not text nodes. This answers both *Is it possible to re-assert that the cursor should change on text hover?* and *If not, is it possible to only use the custom cursor when not hovering text?* Instead, apply your specific cursor explicitly only on those elements where you actually want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a *hacky* idea is to create an extra layer that is not a part of the content (your text) where you apply your cursor

```css
body::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  cursor: move; 
}

body {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  height: 20em;
  background: teal;
}
```

```html
This is some text.  When you hover it, your cursor will not change
```

Comment: Another creative idea by StackoverFlow's CSS master. Even though I wouldn't use such an approach in a production environment (among other reasons for requiring to make `body { position: relative; }` which can cause alot of problems with regard to overflowing content), it's still a creative approach. Of course it will fail as soon as any element has whitespace as that area will still not show the `move` cursor.

Comment: @connexo I myself won't use this idea in a production environnement ;) it's more to show the possibilities to achieve the expected result when we are stuck with a code we cannot change.

Comment: @SephReed Beware of the downsides that setting `position: relative;` on the `body` can have, especially with overflow and absolute positioned children. That can lead to all sorts of weird-seeming, hard-to-debug problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can only target elements with CSS, not text nodes.

This answers both

> Is it possible to re-assert that the cursor should change on text hover?
> If not, is it possible to only use the custom cursor when not hovering text?

Instead, apply your specific cursor explicitly only on those elements where you actually want it.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to wrap your text in a `<p>` or other tags, and re-init the cursor for them.

```css
body { 
  height: 20em;
  background: teal;
  cursor: move; 
}
p {
  cursor: initial;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text in P tags.  When you hover it, your cursor will change</p>
```